# The audio duration is undefined

Tags: jquery

Do you know why audio duration appears undefined?

This is the code:

```
<div class="drag">
  drag
  <audio id="audio" src="www.freesfx.co.uk/rx2/mp3s/11/12840_1448729631.mp3"></audio>
</div>

<div class="drop">drop</div>
```

```
$(function() {   
  $(".drag").draggable({
    revert: 'invalid'
  });
  $(".drop").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui){
      var audlen = $('#audio').duration;
      alert(audlen);
      $(ui.draggable).css({width:audlen + 'px'});
    }
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hfy3dwf5/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not correctly set the `src` of the video correctly. You need to add a `<source>` tag which allows you to correctly link your file. This is nested within the `<audio>` tag.

You should also specify a `type` attribute which isn't necessary for this to work, but good practice.

```
<div class="drag">
  drag
  <audio id="audio" type="audio/mp3">
        <source src="http://www.freesfx.co.uk/rx2/mp3s/11/12840_1448729631.mp3">
  </audio>
</div>

<div class="drop">drop</div>
```

Additionally, you can access the div via `getElementById` to make this work.

```
$(function() {   
  $(".drag").draggable({
    revert: 'invalid'
  });
  $(".drop").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui){

       var audlen = document.getElementById("audio");
       alert(audlen.duration);

      $(ui.draggable).css({width:audlen + 'px'});
    }
  });
});
```

As a result, dragging the `drag div` into the `drop div` will return *12.199184*

Edit: See the JSFiddle for a working demo https://jsfiddle.net/ghxsnr91/

Comment: Just a note: `$('#audio')` is jQuery that does the exact same thing as `document.getElementById("audio")`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but now it appears NaN instead of undefined!